# Find solutions and get a first statement for these diophantine equations inspired in certain figurate numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Yesterday I was thinking in speculative relationships between certain figurate numbers, please see if you need the tables, and references from the article of the
encyclopedia MathWorld [*Figurate Number.*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FigurateNumber.html).

I wondered about speculative relationships of the type: First I take a *prism* of basis the hex number and $z$ as height, we represent the hex number of this basis with the integer $x$. Secondly we do the same thing, we multiply $z$ by a centered pentagonal number using $y$ in its representation to build a second prism. Finally we try the comparison

$$z\cdot\left(\text{hex number}\right)+z\cdot\left(\text{centered pentagonal number}\right)=\text{Haüy octahedral number}$$
where the variable for the representation of our Haüy octahedral number in RHS is precisely the height $z$. Such equation for positive integers $x,y,z\geq 1$ is equivalent to
$$18x^2z+18xz+15y^2z+15yz-8z^3+12z^2-4z+6=0\tag{1}.$$

Other equation that I've considered was

$$z\cdot\left(\text{hex number}\right)-z\cdot\left(\text{centered pentagonal number}\right)=\text{Haüy octahedral number}$$
that is equivalent to

$$18 x^2 z + 18 x z - 15 y^2 z - 15 y z - 8 z^3 + 12 z^2 - 16 z + 6=0\tag{2}.$$

> **Question.** Can you find solutions of $(1)$ or $(2)$? Please, see below the computational facts. What can be a first professional step/statement that one can to deduce in the study of these equations $(1)$ or $(2)$? I am asking about how get a first professional proposition (what is a first interesting statement) for some of these equations, when one evokes the study of these equations. **Many thanks.**

**Fact.** If we divide by $2$ the genuine equations, if I am not wrong, it is easy to prove that we only to need check the equations for odd integers $z\geq 1$ and integers $y\geq 1$ such the correspinding centered pentagonal number is an even integer, since the other cases are absurd. I can not deduce a similar statement for the congrence $\equiv\text{ mod }3$ (when we divide the equation by $3$). For each equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ Wolfram Alpha online calculator provide me partial derivaties and the polynomial discriminant, but I don't know it is useful to solve the problem in my Question.

**Computational facts.**

1. I can not to find solutions $(x,y,z)$ of the equation  $(1)$ for integers $x,y,z\geq 1$ when our integers run over the segments $1\leq x\leq 300$ and  $1\leq y\leq 300$ and  $1\leq z\leq 300$.
2. Similarly for the second equation and same segments of integers, our difference of figurate numbers $(2)$, I can find only the solutions $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ and  $(x,y,z)=(31,34,1)$

Comment: Trivial observation for both equations: $z\mid 6$.

Comment: So we can replace each equation by a small number of equations in the two variables $x,y$.

Comment: Since 142929, true to form, is unlikely to tell us what those octahedral numbers are, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_octahedral_number says they are $(2n+1)(2n^2+2n+3)/3$.

Comment: When $z=1$, (1) becomes $18x^2+18x+15y^2+15y+6=0$ which, obviously, has no positive solutions.

Comment: Many thanks @GerryMyerson and Wojowu. I think that are very good observations.

Comment: Then it is possible to prove that there aren't solutions of the equation $(1)$, since the case $z=3$ also is absurd.

Comment: $$(2)\overset{z\to1}{\implies}\Bigl(5 (2 y + 1)\Bigr)^2 - 30 \Bigl(2 x + 1\Bigr)^2 = -45$$ this Pell equation with infinite set positive solutions.

Comment: So said it seems simple, but I think it is very clever. Many thanks for your excellent contribution, feel free to post it as a answer if you consider expand your comment as an answer. Many thanks @DmitryEzhov